# How to fix Floating point exception: 8 in C code

Tags: c, primes

I'm trying to write a program that lists all prime numbers in a given parameter. My terminal won't output anything, even though I have a print function at the end of the program.

Could you also let me know if the x and g variables were necessary or could I have just stuck with i.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 1000
int main(){

    int N , i, x, g, a[MAX_SIZE];

    scanf("%d", &N);

    a[0] = 2;

    for (i = 1; i < N - 2; i++)
    {
        a[i] = (a[i-1]) + 1;
    }

    for (x = 0; x < N - 2; x++){
        for (i = 1; i < N - 2; i++){
            if (a[i] % a[x] == 0) {
                for (g = i; g < N - 2; g++){
                    a[g] = a[g+1];
                }
            }
        }
    }


    for (i = 0; i < N - 2; i++){
        printf("%d \n", a[i]);
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you get a floating point exception in code that doesn't have any floating point math, it can only mean one thing: divide by 0.

Comment: Not understanding the algorithm well, the cause of error is division by zero at `a[i] % a[x]`.

Comment: You should use indents to make your code easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

You have off-by-one error here:

```
for (g = i; g < N - 2; g++){
  a[g] = a[g+1];

}
```

When `g = N - 2 - 1`, the value `a[N - 2]` is used, but the element is not initialized and the value is indeterminate.

You should check and fix your algorithm not to read uninitialized element.

---

Your code looks too complicated for me. Here is an example of my code to print all prime numbers that are `N` or less:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int N;
    int* primes;
    int prime_count;
    int i, j;
    if (scanf("%d", &N) != 1) return 1;
    primes = malloc(sizeof(*primes) * N);
    if (primes == NULL) return 2;

    prime_count = 0;
    for (i = 2; i <= N; i++) {
        int is_prime = 1;
        for (j = 0; j < prime_count; j++) {
            if (i % primes[j] == 0) {
                is_prime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (is_prime) primes[prime_count++] = i;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < prime_count; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", primes[i]);
    }

    free(primes);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But doesn't letting g = i give g a value? I think you're referring to g anyway, im only a beginner XD

Comment: @ChrisThomas It is giving `g` a value, but it is not giving `a[N-2]` a value.

Comment: At what stage do I assign the array position N - 2 ? Also, the reason I need to use that version of code is because my lecturer specified thats how our algorithm should work

Comment: @ChrisThomas My guess is the element should not be assigned and the condition `g < N - 2` should be replaced with `g + 1 < N - 2`.

Comment: @ChrisThomas The `g` loop is removing an element from the array. After removing the element, the array is shorter by 1, and `N` has to be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: @user3386109 how would I do that?